# Macros for Comapring columns with dates and Id and highlighting them

Tags: vba, excel

I have columns A, B, D, E
Column A  contains ID and column B conatins only the matching ID. (sometimes there are no ID found in column B) and Column D  contains source Date and Column E contains start date.(column E sometime doesnt have any date)

I Need to compare the Dates and paste result in column f that the Project has started.

I have 4 cases for that.

Case 1. If the sorce date is < 4 weeks of start date, then print Project on time.

case 2: if the source date is > 8 weeks of start date , then print Project delay.

case 3: If there are Id present in the column A and B and there is no start date found in column E , then it should print Project remaining.

Case 4 : there are no id present in Column B and no source date found, then print nothing.

I have coded for comparing the Dates, but i am struck how i should compare it with Id in case 3.

```
Sub dateCompare()

Dim r As Long, zLastRow As Long
Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long
Dim Ztext  As String

zLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To zLastRow
    If Len(Trim(Cells(r, "E"))) = 0 Then

    Cells(r, 6) = " Remaining"
    Cells(r, 6).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Cells(r, 7) = "Yellow"
   Else
    zWeeks = DateDiff("w", Cells(r, "D"), Cells(r, "E"))

        Select Case zWeeks
            Case Is > 8
                zcolour = vbRed
                Ztext = "Delayed " & Int(zWeeks) & " weeks"
                Cells(r, 7) = "Red"
            Case Is < 4
                zcolour = vbGreen
                Ztext = " On- Time"
                Cells(r, 7) = " Green"

          Case 4 To 8
          zcolour = vbYellow
          Ztext = "Remaining"
          Cells(r, 7) = "Yellow"

            Case Else
                zcolour = none
                Ztext = " check for dates"
        End Select

        Cells(r, "F").Interior.Color = zcolour
        Cells(r, "F") = Ztext
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you actually need to save those colors? Otherwise, conditional formatting is an easier way.

Comment: i Need saving ´those colours, because in later stage of my Evaluation i am using them. @ josef Hoppe

Comment: Why VBA and not Excel formulas :)

Comment: Because, I wanted to practice with vb. thats why :) @SiddharthRout

Comment: If you know the excel formula then you can write a 2-3 liner VB code to achieve the same result. You will not need such a long code as posted above ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am completely new to VBA, If you could do it simple, Please do help me to write a simple code, satisfying the criteria

Comment: Ok Gimme 15 mins

Comment: @SiddharthRout you have 2 minutes left ;)

Comment: Well Well. Refresh the page @ShaiRado ;)

Comment: @Mikz did you test the code above ? because it works, the **case 3** is taken care of in the section `If Len(Trim(Cells(r, "E"))) = 0 Then`, **case 1, 2, 4** are the `Else` with the `Select Case zWeeks`

Comment: BTW in `DateDiff("w", Cells(r, "D"), Cells(r, "E"))`  for weeks you have to use "ww" instead of "w"

Comment: I have updated my post to incorporate your code as well. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Case 1. If the sorce date is < 4 weeks of start date, then print Project on time.

```
=IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(D2,E2,"d")/7,5)<4,"Project in Time","-")
```

> case 2: if the source date is > 8 weeks of start date , then print Project delay.

```
=IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(E2,D2,"d"),7)/7>8,"Project Delay","-")
```

> case 3: If there are Id present in the column A and B and there is no start date found in column E , then it should print Project remaining.

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"",B2<>""),IF(E2="","Project remaining",""),"")
```

> Case 4 : there are no id present in Column B and no source date found, then print nothing.

```
=IF(AND(B2="",D2=""),"Nothing","")
```

Now you have 4 formulas. Simply join them and you will get

`=IF(AND(B2="",D2=""),"Nothing",IF(AND(A2<>"",B2<>""),IF(E2="","Project remaining",IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(E2,D2,"d"),7)/7>8,"Project Delay",IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(D2,E2,"d")/7,5)<4,"Project in Time",""))),""))`

To use that in VBA simply do this

```
With Range("F2:F" & zLastRow)
    .Formula = "=IF(AND(B2="""",D2=""""),""Nothing"",IF(AND(A2<>"""",B2<>"""")," & _
               "IF(E2="""",""Project remaining"",IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(E2,D2,""d"")," & _
               "7)/7>8,""Project Delay"",IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(D2,E2,""d"")/7,5)<4" & _
               ",""Project in Time"",""""))),""""))"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Tested with the following scenario

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code used for testing**

```
Sub Sample()
    zLastRow = 5
    With Range("F2:F" & zLastRow)
        .Formula = "=IF(AND(B2="""",D2=""""),""Nothing"",IF(AND(A2<>"""",B2<>"""")," & _
                   "IF(E2="""",""Project remaining"",IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(E2,D2,""d"")," & _
                   "7)/7>8,""Project Delay"",IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(D2,E2,""d"")/7,5)<4" & _
                   ",""Project in Time"",""""))),""""))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note**: I am sure that there can be a much better formula than what I came up with but you get the gist of using formulas in VBA. It reduces the lines of code.

**EDIT**:

Actually the 4th condition is not important. This formula can also work

`=IF(AND(A2<>"",B2<>""),IF(E2="","Project remaining",IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(E2,D2,"d"),7)/7>8,"Project Delay",IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(D2,E2,"d")/7,5)<4,"Project in Time",""))),"")`

So the VBA equivalent is

```
Sub Sample()
    zLastRow = 5
    With Range("F2:F" & zLastRow)
        .Formula = "=IF(AND(A2<>"""",B2<>""""),IF(E2="""",""Project remaining""," & _
                    "IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(E2,D2,""d""),7)/7>8,""Project Delay""," & _
                    "IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(D2,E2,""d"")/7,5)<4,""Project in Time"",""""))),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If you want to follow your way then do this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long
    Dim Ztext As String

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant code

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            zWeeks = DateDiff("ww", .Range("E" & i).Value, .Range("D" & i).Value)

            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
                Ztext = "Project remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
            ElseIf zWeeks < 4 Then
                Ztext = "Project on time"
                zcolour = vbGreen
            ElseIf zWeeks > 8 Then
                Ztext = "Project delayed"
                zcolour = vbRed
            End If

            With .Range("F" & i)
                .Value = Ztext
                .Interior.Color = zcolour
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** For weeks you have to use `ww` instead of `w` in `DateDiff`

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: didn't test it, but I love the "simply" part ;) indeed a very short and simple formula. However, you need to have Red color for Project Delay

Comment: I am sure the red colour part can be taken care by conditional formatting ;) Also for the `Simple` part, you may have missed the `Note` at the end of the post :D

Comment: +1 just for making this long formula work, I mishandle these, too many `"`, I find the VBA solution above easier to implement and edit, in fact it's mine ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado: I have nothing against the code (yours as you mentioned) OP posted. I am sure there are lot of formula experts in SO. Barry houdini and Scott Craner are formula experts and I am sure they can come up with a much better formula than me. The idea is to use formula over VBA and if one still needs to use VBA then port that formula to VBA. Lot of less code and much faster than looping in the code. Like I said.. nothing against the VBA code posted :D

Comment: I was trying to make a joke ;) don't get too serious

Comment: lol@ShaiRado. Didn't know that and hence din't want you to feel bad ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado ofcourse , the credit for most of my programming knowledge goes to you ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Amazing. :) Thanks a ton for your support.

Comment: @ShaiRado  you both are rocking ;) . i wish i would learn a lot from you both. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout you both are rocking ;) . i wish i would learn a lot from you both.

Comment: @SiddharthRout  there is a Problem with case "Project Delay". I dont have any ID in Column B and no date in Column E, Still the comment appears to be Project delayed . How should i overcome this.

Comment: @SiddharthRout there is the same Problem with the other vba as well. how should i overcome

Comment: With the formula in VB code, sometimes the Status are getting printed and sometime they are not.

Comment: Delete everything in Col F and retry it. The code works just fine for me. I hope you have not made any changes to my code?

Comment: no @ siddharth Rout I have not changed anything to your code. of course, the program satisfied almost all my criteria. Just one Problem, There are no ID in column B ,column D contains   a date and no date in Column E, in this case, column F should be empty. but it prints Project is delayed.

Comment: @SiddharthRout kindly direct me to overcome this

Comment: What should happen if B="", E="", D="Some date"? @Mikz

Answer (score 1):

```
  If Cells(r, "A") <> "" And Cells(r, "B") <> "" And Cells(r, "E") = "" Then
    ' do something

  End If
```